# Having problems adding users to an Active Directory group using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, directoryservices, active-directory-group

Okay, my problem right now is we're trying to write code that will add a user to a different group in our Active Directory. This is the solution we've written.

Part of the main method:

```
string newGroup = "TestDelete";
string userName = result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
string adduser = ad.AddToGroup(userName, newGroup);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} : {1}",userName, adduser));
```

Which calls this method from another class:

```
public String AddToGroup(string userDn, string groupDn)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=" + groupDn + ",DC=blah,DC=blah,DC=blah");
        ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

        string newUser = "CN=" + userDn + "CN=Members,DC=blah,DC=blah,DC=blah";

        ldapConnection.Invoke("Add", new object[] { newUser });
        ldapConnection.CommitChanges();
        ldapConnection.Close();

        return "Success";
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + E.ToString());
    }
}
```

It's throwing the exception

> *System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020006): Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))
>
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.InvokeSet(String propertyName, Object[] args)
>
>   at adjustUsers.Program.AddToGroup(String userDn, String groupDn) in C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\UserPruning\adjustUsers\Program.cs:line 45
>
>   at UserPruning.MainProgram.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\UserPruning\UserPruning\MainProgram.cs:line 46*

Which, as far as we've been able to find indicates a problem with our syntax.

Line 46 is

```
string adduser = ad.AddToGroup(userName,newGroup)
```

Line 45 is

```
ldapConnection.Invoke("Add", new object[] {newUser});
```

We've been trying to rewrite this piece of code for the last day and are still stumped.

Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find your user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
        // find the group in question
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "TestDelete");

        // if found....
        if (group != null)
        {
            // add user to group
            group.Members.Add(user);
            group.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this answer more than once. I feel like almost everything online that I found about AD manipulation via C# links to the Howto: (Almost) Everything in Active Directory via C# [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C] article, which uses the DirectoryEntry API. The DirectoryServices API is *much* nicer! Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem is that the AccountManagement namespace only works if the computer running it is on that domain and can resolve the domains you're querying.

Comment: I'm Querying another domain it can be the reason getting exception 'Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355).' ?